# Uploading a file using Qt

Tags: python, c++, rest, qt, bottle

I've made this resftful webservice using Python Bottle:

```
@route( '/subirArchivo', method=['OPTIONS', 'POST'] )  
@enable_cors
def subirArchivo(  ):
  archivoSubir = request.files.get( "miarchivo" )
  archivoSubir.save( "./subidos/%s" % archivoSubir.filename )
  return { "estado": "correcto" }
```

I need to upload this from a Qt application. I've loaded a file using QFile class but I'm not sure about how to proceed. I have this:

```
        QUrl url;
        url.setPath("/subirArchivo");
        url.addQueryItem("miarchivo", archivo ); // 

        http->setHost( "localhost:8080" );
        http->get( url.toString( ) );
```

Anyway I don't know how to handle "archivo" (QFile) or if this is the best way to go. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you want to send file then use `post()` instead of `get()`. Even in bottle you defined `method=['POST']` for this.

Comment: Qt Centre: [Upload file to HTTP server](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/40734-Upload-file-to-HTTP-server)